# SSH won't ask me for password AND then 2FA OTP (QR)

Tags: ssh, password, openvpn, two-factor-authentication

I've being trying to set up my first ever (minimal?) Ubuntu 20 VPS and I have reached a learning point where I can secure and tune control for other users. I have being trying so far to setup 2FA from google with the QR code. But I don't want to create public keys for every computer that I will have to connect to the vps and just scan the QR code to login. `libpam-google-authenticator` (OTP for android with the green app doesn't find security key, but other do). The thing is I want to type firstly the password and then scan the QR so I can laterally have 2 factors of authentication.
I have being following tutorials and copy pasting commands like
`PasswordAuthentication no`, `ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes UsePAM yes` and `AuthenticationMethods publickey,password publickey,keyboard-interactive` (sometimes there are no errors on sshd)

I have being playing around with theese setting but most of the time it other locks me out and I have to reinstall the machine via the provided controll panel or someother times it denies my login with the correct generated code.

Can you give me an idea for I wish to make:  First ask for the password and then the one time use password. I have read almost hundreds of blogs-post but I can't understand how to do this... I even tried `AuthenticationMethods password,keyboard-interactive` To ask first for the password and then the one time password but nothing. I've reset my machine 10000 times because I'm getting logged out every time! Also, to my understanding I can't shit on a strangers computer and generate public keys in order to access my VPS every time

I can clearly see and understand most of things in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` but that thing `AuthenticationMethods`  I can't get it to successfully ask for password first and then the OneTimePassword

> Before I reinstall my system again I'm following this tutorial: https://notthebe.ee/Creating-your-own-OpenVPN-server.html
> Ye's I'm a beginner and I start from simpler things, but I'm not seeking for a solution (just follow the tutorial and be done) I'm looking for more, for a path to learn more

Best regards,

-Clearly a windows 10 HOME user